# Query a list with the top N elements in each group

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, orm, django-orm

Let's say i have two models:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    b = foreignKey(ModelB)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(...)
```

What i need is to keep only N latest results related each modelb and delete the rest. The table ModelB and Result can really have many records.
Is there a way i can perform this with django ORM without having to create a loop?

**[Edit]- Example**:

```
ModelB objs: [(1, [result1, result2, result3, result4]), (2, [result10, result11, result12])]

Result objs: [(result1), (result2), (result3), (result4), (result10), (result11), (result12)]
```

let's say i want to keep only the 2 latest results from the subset of each Modelb , the remaining should be the following

```
ModelB objs:  [(1, [result4, result3]), (2, result12, result11)]
Result objs: [(result3), (result4), (result11), (result12)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `created` field to the model(s) so you know when an object was created. You can then order on this to find the latest `N` instances.

```
class Result(models.Model):
    b = foreignKey(ModelB)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "created"
```

As far as deleting objects goes, you could do something like;

```
n = 10
results = Result.objects.all().count()

if results > n:
    all_results = Result.objects.all()
    keep = all_results[n:]
    keep_ids = keep.values_list('id', flat=True)
    all_results.exclude(id__in=keep_ids).delete()
```

It's probably also worth noting the [`get_latest_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#get-latest-by) attribute of model meta which allows you to define how to identify the newest instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there is not deleting from each subset.
Sorry, i think i missed an example, so i edit adding it to the question.

Comment: @SaturninoMateus based on what you've added, you've got a list of tuples. So you'd have to iterate over the list and delete what you don't want from the results each time.

Comment: that was just to ilustrate. All i have are the models, and i'm trying to find a more efficient way without having to iterate manually.

Comment: @SaturninoMateus if all you have is the models, then implement the concept I've illustrated to control the number of objects you keep.